# How do I prove a class-room scheduling issue to be NP complete correctly?

Tags: complexity-theory, traveling-salesman, np, np-complete

I am given a problem, that is about scheduling n classes in k rooms at a school, and it is a decision problem, because we want to ask if we can arrange these n classes in those k rooms so that a given timelimit t is not exceeded (the total time of classes in a certain scheduled way should not exceed t).

I am aware about to firstly show that every solution to the problem can be verified in polynomial time, but when it comes to reducing some known NP complete problem to the class-room scheduling problem then I do not know which NP-complete problem I should take.

I was thinking about using Traveling Salesman Problem to reduce, but I am not sure about how to interpret my class-room scheduling problem into a graph considering the symbolics. My first attempt to interpret my problem as a graph is to consider the classes as vertices, rooms as colours and the time for a class denoted by a weighted edge between two classes (the latter two interpretations completely unsure). But I don't know if this follows a standard pattern for some scheduling problem or I don't even know if Traveling Salesman Problem is a good NP-complete problem to reduce to the class-room scheduling problem. In the latter case, then I would like to know examples of more suitable NP-complete problems to reduce in my case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [map-coloring (graph-coloring)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) for it. You just need to define rules for edges and nodes. Nodes will be classes, rooms will be colors and you connect classes that can't be in same time. This is actually k-coloring problem, where you need to color specific graph with k colors in order to minimize number of classes per color. However in this special case, you just need to have less or equal to t per color. You can achieve this by going by standard rule of coloring, and switch to new color as soon as it has t number of classes.

This is still a NP-complete problem. Only exception is when you have 1 or 2 classes, then its in polynomial time. When you have 1 room, you just need to check if `n<=t`. When you have 2 rooms, you just need to check if it can be colored by 2 colors. You can achieve this by DFS (but first check if n <= 2t) and color odd steps with first color and even steps with second color. If it is possible to color all nodes with this tactic, you have a positive solution. When `k>=3`, its [NP-complete](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/recitations/rec21-graphs/graphs.htm).

Comment: I remember that I by some reason also thought about using graph coloring, but in some sense I thought that I did not know how to relate the the graph coloring to the problem above.

I thought that the vertices in a graph could be the classes and the colors the rooms the classes are to be scheduled on. But what sense would the edges have? Perhaps that they denote independency between two classes (i.e. no teachers/pupils in common), but I am not sure here, so that is the reason I dismissed it :/

Comment: Or how would you have interpreted?

Comment: You can represent nodes as classes. You connect nodes for which classes can't be in the same time (like if professor is lecturing those two classes so he can't do that in the same time) or even in the same room (if you introduce such rule).Now, you need to find minimal number of colors that can be used. The goal is not to have more then k colors (timelimit).

Comment: I see... But one question: how do you handle with the fact that each class have a time length? How would the graph coloring take this into account?

Comment: Okay, maybe I have gotten this:

When proving NP-completeness of a custom problem, then you have to pick a known NP-complete problem to reduce to that custom problem.

We can consider this known NP-complete problem as a "special case" of the custom problem.

When choosing the graph coloring problem, then we assert the vertices to represent the classes, the edges between vertices represent independency (two classes cannot be hold during same period) and the colors the total timelimit. The length of each class is assumed to be 1.

Is this reasoning possibly correct?

Comment: One absolutely last question: how can I deduce the number of rooms from an instance to the graph coloring problem?

Comment: i thought no more then k time in one room... Even if you have different times for different classes, you just need to break it to atomic time, such that t_class_i = x_i * t_atomic, where x is number of nodes for specific class. And you continue in same manner. 
You got it right, its just a matter of setting rules of bijection to know NP problem or several of them.

Comment: Okay, so you have previously assumed that number of rooms at some time is 1, right? But I guess that it should work because, as told, graph coloring is just a special case of the class-room scheduling problem. But is assuming that the number of rooms is 1 completely okay? Despite the assumption, would we still be able to prove the NP completeness of class-room scheduling problem using this technique?

Comment: in gerenal it is... but it can also be different, just break it and setup rule that atomic part must be in same room (or it can be in different - its just a matter of the rules which affect the number of vertexes). Easiest is if you assume its 1. both cases are  actually done in polynomial time.. but for 3+ rooms its NP...

However, if you have 1 room, you just sum it and see if its larger than k, and for 2 rooms you have bipartite graph so just do DFS and use two colors and sum each color to see will one of them will be larger than k.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but don't you now mixing up rooms with colors? Because we are checking that a set of classes can be scheduled on some number of rooms in k time units. If k=1 or k=2, then you're right: it can be done in polynomial time. But when 3<=k, then we have a NP problem. But do you have any link sources to some sites where a random scheduling problem is proved to be NP-complete using graph coloring so I can study further on this subject?

Comment: sorry, my bad... Monday mood yesterday... Your problem is such that you don't search minimal coloring but best distribution per room, such that for each 1<=i<=k you have t_i <= t, where t_i is actually number of classes in room i, or number of classes colored by color i and difference between t_min and t_max is minimal. So your problem is actually "k-colorability problem".

Comment: Finding such distribution is NP problem, but you just need to find the part if there is a coloring (represents rooms) such that for each i,you get t_i <= k.This can be achieved by doing the coloring but watching that t_i doesn't go over k. If that is about to happen, use next free color instead of color i. I will update my answer soon. 
Here is one example:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-ColorableGraph.html